# Using Cytoscape rendering inside twitter boostrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cytoscape.js

I am using two cytoscape graphs inside twitter bootstrap 3 tabs (one graph per tab).

My trouble is that only active tab is renderer, when I select hidden tab it's graph is not rendered (the graph is rendered if I open / close firebug (with F12) on firefox).

I tried to solve this by :

```
$('#view-target').cytoscape({
...
ready: function(){
window.cytoscapeTarget = this;
}
});


$('#show-target').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
window.cytoscapeTarget.forceRender();
});
```

Without success.

The graph is loaded but not rendered, does it come from cytoscape or twitter bootstrap ?

Thanks

Nicolas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to fix Bootstrap so it doesn't use a dimension breaking hide style (i.e. don't use `display: none` etc) or you can force Cy.js to recalculate the dimensions available using [`cy.resize()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/viewport-manipulation/cy.resize).

Note that this caused by limitations in your browser:

(1) DOM elements with certain hidden styles can not have dimensions queried.

(2) The browser has no event or mechanism for detecting CSS/dimension changes on a DOM element.  Workarounds for this are prohibitively expensive.

Comment: Great, it works fine ;-). Just be careful : don't use the resize() call for the cytoscape instance on active tab (first tab displayed), in this case the graph would not reappear ...

Comment: Point (2) is not true (and wasn't the time you were writing this answer- see my answer), but the hint with resize is correct and that gave me inspiration for looking further, so +1 anyway :-)

Comment: I'm using ngx-bootstrap and facing the exact same issue. I'm not able to resolve it using the provided solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same rendering issue inside **Bootstrap modal** also, and the approved answer fixed this issue, I have used

[cy.resize()](http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/viewport-manipulation/cy.resize)

inside

> 'shown.bs.modal'

event and it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by maxkfranz is good, but it lacks actual solution for the problem. Also, it is not true that browser has no mechanism for detecting CSS changes - you can use DOMAttrModified or Mutation Observers (which are handled by most browsers now and make DOMAttrModified obsolete).

Here's my code - I assume that you have your `cytoscape.js` container inside Bootstrap's tab `#cyTab` and using standard cytoscape variable `cy`:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {        
    if(mutation.oldValue == "tab-pane fade" && mutation.target.className == "tab-pane fade active in") {
        console.log('REDRAW!');
        cy.resize();
        cy.layout({name: 'dagre'}); //optional - recalculate whatever layout you wish
    }
  });    
});
var targetNode = $('#cyTab')[0];
var observerConfig = {  
    attributes: true,
    childList: false,
    characterData: false,
    attributeOldValue: true, 
    'attributeFilter': ['class']};
observer.observe(targetNode, observerConfig);
```

You can read more about Mutation Observers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: Mutation observers are not sufficient unless you are able to observe changes to *everything* that could change style.  Your example catches the common class list case, but there are more.  General data attribute changes and DOM hierarchy changes both can affect the style.  There's also stylesheet additions/removals and (async) loading to take into account.  Finally, Cytoscape.js is compatible back to IE9 -- so cy.resize() is still required for compatibility.  I've added an issue to improve this though https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1284

Comment: I beg to disagree with the relevancy of your comment to specific case described in this question - bootstrap tab switching uses `active in`. DOM Hierarchy? Of course, we can move the cytoscape node into totally different place which will render my mechanism invalid, but nevertheless my solution is OK if the developer doesn't want to shoot himself in the foot :-).

Comment: Other users than the asker tend to see the question from search -- and those users are the focus now that the question was asked a year ago.  Their cases are of varying levels of similarity to the asker's, so it's good to have a general solution to better serve the community overall.  I'm sure devs are more than capable of picking and choosing what's relevant to their particular case.