# Cytoscape.js and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, cytoscape.js

I am trying to display two cytoscape.js graphs under each other using Twitter Bootstrap Grid layout. Unfortunately, cytoscape does not respect the size it gets assigned from Bootstrap but uses the whole screen instead. Does anyone of you have an advice how to combine Bootstrap and cytoscape? Moreover, are there any examples of two cytographs below each other?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Please do have a look this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916735/using-cytoscape-rendering-inside-twitter-boostrap-tabs) you may get some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise *after* you've set all your style on the container.  Cytoscape can't get the dimensions of its container if you haven't set them yet.

Comment: Can you provide an example? How can I fix this code: https://jsfiddle.net/j2de3g5n/ so that the graph and form don't overlap.